# Choose image files in a specific directory without prompt

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to set image files to the variable with applescript, like this:

`set targetImg to choose file with prompt "select image" of type {"public.image"} with multiple selections allowed`

With this command, I can set the files with pop-up finder.

But I want to set the files automatically and just tell applescript the directory path of the files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, run your command and choose your desired files. Then, manually set the variable to the result, like so:

```
set targetImg to {alias "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:img01.jpg", alias "MacHD:Users:username:Desktop:img02.jpg"}
```

You can edit the results to include whichever files you like.

Details on how to specify files can be found in the Language Guide under [Aliases and Files](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_fundamentals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH218-SW28).

Comment: Sorry, it seems that the way I provide it was not good. I wanted to choose files without specifying the file name. Finally I wrote like this: `set targetImg to every file of folder "/Users/username/Pictures" whose name ends with ".RW2"` But I appreciate you a lot and I'm gonna study them. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to choose image files is using Uniform Type Identifier (UTI), which for image files is **"public.image"**. Also, choose file has option to indicate **default location** (that is, folder). I used path to pictures folder, but you can use any folder alias instead:

```
set theFolder to path to pictures folder from user domain --> result is alias
set targetImg to choose file of type "public.image" default location theFolder with multiple selections allowed
```

.
.
Since the request is not entirely clear, I'll provide another script here, in case the OP want to indicate a folder and get image files as a result. Again, I am using UTI here. Since UTI is a resource property, we have to apply a repeat loop here:

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set sourceFolder to path to pictures folder from user domain
set imageFiles to my filterFilesListByUTI(sourceFolder, "public.image")

on filterFilesListByUTI(sourceFolder, targUTI)
    tell application "System Events" to set {posixPaths, typeIDs} to {POSIX path, type identifier} of files of sourceFolder
    if posixPaths is {} then return {}
    repeat with i from 1 to (count posixPaths)
        set typeID to item i of typeIDs
        if my filterUTIList({typeID}, targUTI) is {} then set item i of posixPaths to missing value
    end repeat
    return text of posixPaths
end filterFilesListByUTI

on filterUTIList(aUTIList, aUTIstr)
    set anArray to my (NSArray's arrayWithArray:aUTIList)
    set aPred to my NSPredicate's predicateWithFormat_("SELF UTI-CONFORMS-TO %@", aUTIstr)
    return (anArray's filteredArrayUsingPredicate:aPred) as list
end filterUTIList
```

Here is plain-AppleScript version, it is twice faster than AsObjC version above.:

```
set sourceFolder to path to pictures folder from user domain
set imageFiles to my filterFilesListByUTI(sourceFolder, "public.image")

on filterFilesListByUTI(sourceFolder, targUTI)
    -- get Posix paths of files of source folder
    tell application "System Events" to set posixPaths to POSIX path of files of sourceFolder
    if posixPaths is {} then return {}
    -- build shell command to get info for mutilpe files at once
    set shellCommand to "mdls -name kMDItemContentTypeTree "
    repeat with posixPath in posixPaths
        set shellCommand to shellCommand & quoted form of posixPath & space
    end repeat
    -- get info for mutilpe files at once, split info on sections
    set ATID to AppleScript's text item delimiters
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "kMDItemContentTypeTree ="
    set theInfo to text items of (do shell script shellCommand)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ATID
    -- remove Posix paths of files whose info section doesn't contain targUTI
    set i to 1
    repeat with posixPath in posixPaths
        set i to i + 1
        if (contents of item i of theInfo) does not contain targUTI then set contents of posixPath to missing value
    end repeat
    text of posixPaths
end filterFilesListByUTI
```

Comment: Your plain AppleScript version is slow because it's not very well written.  You've got **nested** repeat loops, within which you **call out to the shell** ***every*** iteration!  It works, and it accurately filters the files in my downloads folder, but it took over two minutes to do so, but if you optimise the implementation, _System Events_ can return the same result in a tenth of a second.

Comment: Your comment is taken into account by me as quite useful in this case. I made significant changes to the last script, which made it about 2 times faster than its AsObjC analog.

Comment: This script works perfectly. Thank you so much Mr. Robert Kniazidis. I didn't know that apple script can make something like method by `on` Interesting...